# Deleting multiple same id from mysql database

Tags: laravel-5

Below is my code for deleting all rows with ids one.It seems that only first index was deleted
and an error will trigger right away.How can i loop through the array and delete all rows with id one.
The array I've created here is only a representation from my database with multiple columns.
Any idea in resolving this problem is much appreciated.

```
public function deleteRow(){

 $ids = ['1','1','1','3','3','1','1'];


    foreach($ids as $id ){
      $id = Scholarshipcount::find($id);
      $id->delete();    
    }
}
```

my error

Call to a member function delete() on a non-object

Answer (score 1):

`Find()` can fail to find the record, especially of you have multiple times the same PK as in your example (and you have already deleted the object the first time). You might want to consider using `findOrFail` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different kind of approach instead. Assuming that your table name is `scholarshipcounts` then:

```
DB::table('scholarhipcounts')->whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
```